# Eliminating all apple telemetry

Tags: macos, security, performance, privacy

Using Lulu, and turning off the "allow apple processes" option, You can see that apple makes hundreds of connections to the internet for a variety of reasons.

I did an experiment: I blocked all outgoing Apple connections. For weeks, new connections popped up every day, I can't remember how many I blocked but it must have been around 200.

The result? System instability. The inability to connect caused the MacBook Pro to get really sludgy. I did not have the foresight to see if it was connected to the CPU load, but there you have it. I did not change anything in the system, install any new apps, or anything like that in the time I did the experiment.

Here's the catch though:

If I turn off any internet connection, the MacBook will run smoothly into infinity, never being allowed to connect.

It makes sense, the backlog causes issues. But it is almost like a punishment as well.

My question:

Is it possible to eliminate these processes at a lower level (kernel extensions? I'm not knowledgeable enough) to just eliminate the macbook's need to connect entirely for anything?

Would there be any real drawbacks? Would this prevent security definitions from being updated resulting in vulnerabilities, perhaps?

TIA

Comment: This seems to be an issue of [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt) clouding judgement. The interweb fears "telemetry" whilst not fully understanding what it is &/or when it is used - resulting in people searching for ways to "switch it off" unnecessarily.

Comment: For the purpose of this question, how is telemetry defined? You correctly describe communications that serve functions such as setting time, OCSP/CRL, APNS, anti-tamper protections, anti malware updates, security updates as well as opt in items like Siri, iCloud, crash reporting to list some prominent features.

Comment: Also, software that runs smoothly into infinity sure sounds like paradise!

Comment: To infinity ... and beyond!

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem here is that you think all these connections are "telemetry". They're not. At least not using a common understanding of what telemetry is.

The easiest fix for your problem is simply not to block these connections - then you will not experience that slowness.

The slowness comes from fact that various programs and system services rely on Apple's server for various functionality. If you do not block those in the right manner, these programs will just think the server is slow to respond - so they wait and wait for a reply until finally timing out. This is then the slowness you perceive.

For example you're trying to run an application you've downloaded from the Mac App Store. The system will ask Apple's servers whether this app has been revoked due to security issues before running it. If it is not blocked correctly that will introduce a wait for you. Even when it is blocked correctly, you still loose the functionality that Apple can stop malicious software from being run without warning on your computer.

Yes, if you really want you can eliminate these "processes" - it does not take kernel extensions to do so. You can just kill and/or remove the programs involved. I wouldn't recommend doing so.

In terms of drawbacks - yes, there are real drawbacks in blocking these connections. And yes, of course security definitions cannot be updated since you've purposely blocked that - so that could result in vulnerabilities. Similarly you wouldn't be getting software updates. In addition to that, your system will no longer know when certificates for your installed software have been revoked (OCSP) - and as such, you leave the system vulnerable there as well.